# How do I conditionally modify a button's (or other UIView) property?

Tags: properties, uibutton, swiftui

Scenario:

I would like to toggle an entity (UIView)'s property; 
 like a button's color and perhaps other characteristics per @State boolean var.

```
Button(action: {
    self.showActionSheet.toggle()
}) {
    Text("Action Sheet")
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}
.padding()
.background(Color.blue)// how do I toggle this conditionally: i.e. one of two colors?
.cornerRadius(10)
.shadow(radius: 10)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a Button conditionally hidden or disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420386/how-do-you-make-a-button-conditionally-hidden-or-disabled) Which is your question you accepted the answer on a few minutes ago. Please, if that was an acceptable answer, help everyone nd edit that question.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Replaced image with sample code per feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User the ternary operator:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .background(flag ? Color.orange : Color.blue)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.flag.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```