# Toggle Sidebar in SwiftUI NavigationView on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have a macOS Application with a `NavigationView` and want to have the default ToggleSidebar item in the toolbar of the window.

Currently I set the target of the ToolbarItem to the AppDelegate in `toolbarWillAddItem(_)` of the `NSToolbarDelegate`.

Inside of the AppDelegate I implemented

```swift
@objc func toggleSidebar(_ sender: Any) {
    ((window.contentView?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first as? NSSplitView)?.delegate as? NSSplitViewController)?.toggleSidebar(self)
}
```

This solution is working right now. If the implementation of SwiftUI will change this breaks.

**So how can this be done in a better way?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since macOS Big Sur beta 4 you can add default sidebar commands with SwiftUI 2.0.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                SidebarView()
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
    .commands {
        SidebarCommands()
    }
}
```

This code will add the "Toggle Sidebar" shortcut:

[image]

SidebarView code:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            Text("\(index)")
        }
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to SwiftUI (not a newbie programmer though); it seems, that just attaching `.commands { SidebarCommands() }` to the `WindowGroup` did the trick (I already had a `NavigationView`, but it vanished). Thanks for your suggestion and help (tried on XCode 14.3, MacOS 13.x).

Answer (score 8):

While you could try to perform `#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:))` on `keyWindow?.contentViewController` or `keyWindow?.firstResponder?`, it appears  that this doesn't work consistently in some situations.

Instead, you can use this command:

```swift
NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), to: nil, from: nil)
```

It sends the `toggleSidebar` selector to the first object that can react to it, meaning, the only sidebar in the current window. This behavior is better documented [on Apple's documentation website.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428509-sendaction/)

---

This method is the default implementation used by the `SidebarCommands()` menu item. This is found by adding the *Toggle Sidebar* menu item, then fetching it's selector like so:

```swift
let menu = NSApp.mainMenu!.items.first(where: { $0.title == "View" })!
let submenu = menu.submenu!.items.first(where: { $0.title == "Toggle Sidebar" })!
submenu.target // nil
submenu.action // #selector(toggleSidebar:)
```

This means that it will most likely be more consistent (and supported) than the other methods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @diogo, especially for showing what Apple is using under the hood!

Answer (score 7):

In SwiftUI 2.0 you can use `NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)` with a toolbar button like this:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
        #if os(macOS)
        Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        })
        #endif
    }
}

func toggleSidebar() {
    #if os(macOS)
    NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
    #endif
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly if you use the three panels layout (sidebar, primary, detail). `NSApp.keyWindow?.contentViewController?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)` is better at this and will work also if the primary or detail panel or one of their subviews is the first responder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use NavigationView for this. Use a HSplitView instead and use a hidden flag like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228385/811010