# Is there a way to make a transparent view but hide a view behind it and between background

Tags: swift, swiftui

Edit: not a code question or help me with an assignment or anything. Just had a thought: if one view being transparent still can hide another behind it but above the background

If I get views **T** -> **I** -> **B** where **T** is top view visible, **I** is behind top view and **B** is background.

Can I make **T** view transparent so the **B** background is visible but **I** is still hidden by **T** top view?

I played with ZStack and clipped attribute with no luck

Comment: Would you show your code? And it would be great if you'd demo somehow which effect you try to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want something like this. You could either not present I VC or just hide it with the `isHidden` property

Answer (score 1):

Put T and I in the same ZStack

```
ZStack{
 BView()
 ZStack{
  IView()
  TView()
 }.isHidden(boolean)

}
```

While you can create *isHidden* modifier like this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228385/6041952)
Or you can just play on the opacity