# How to hide view in SwiftUI based on condition?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one SwiftUI view which i want to hide on specific condition.
Also I want empty space hidden should not remove the view space. is there any way to do this in SwiftUI?

for ex. bellow Text i want to hide if number == 1 and show if number == 0

```
Text("Test")
  .hidden()
```

how to hive condition in SwiftUI

I can do bellow but its repetitive code.

```
if number == 1 {
    Text("Test")
      .hidden()
}
else {
   Text("Test")
}
```

Please suggest better solution.

Thank you for help.

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420479/3585796), you need `opacity`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same without `else` part:

```
if number != 1 {
    Text("Test")
}
```

Comment: You may add the complete body, to see the context and to make it clear, that the statements are written in a ViewBuilder ;)