# How to make a view gone in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to hide view but noticed that `view.hidden()` will only hide the view but but the space remains.

I also tried some of the suggestions on this link [Dynamically hiding view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490250/dynamically-hiding-view-in-swiftui)
But it didn't really work for me, albeit it was a starting point.

Find below what I finally did.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach without an extension.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hidden = false
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    Toggle("Hide", isOn: $hidden.animation(Animation.easeInOut))
                }
                
                if !hidden {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Pin", text: $text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: hidden]

Comment: I am yet to understand why people create overly complex extensions to do things like this instead of keeping it simple like you have done here. 

Comment: @Fogmeister I agree, just keep it simple. Thank you! 

Answer (score -2):

I created an extension function as below

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func hiddenConditionally(isHidden: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        isHidden.wrappedValue ? self  :  self.hidden() as? Self
    }
}
```

and you can call it as below

```swift
         TextField("Pin", text: $pin)
                .hiddenConditionally(isHidden: $showPinField)
```

Comment: Why make it simple when you can over complicate it.