# SwiftUI: List background is black when it is an empty List

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

My List looks like this:

```
List(viewModel.exerciseSelection, id: \.id) { exercise in
    AddWorkoutDetailView(exerciseName: exercise.name, gifImage: exercise.gifUrl)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowBackground(Color.backgroundColor)
        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
            Button(role: .destructive) {
                                
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
            }
        }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.listRowBackground(Color.backgroundColor)
```

---

EDIT:
My whole View is structured like this:

```
NavigationStack { 
    ZStack {
        Color.backgroundColor
            .ignoresSafeArea()

        VStack {
            // some other stuff
            List {
                // my list from above
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Problem is, that when my `List` is empty, there will be a black background and not my custom background color, which is present when the `List` is populated.

[image: Empty List]

[image: Populated List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Bug in `SwiftUI` but first of all:

You are using `listRowBackground` modifier instead of `background` on the `List` and there is no Row to background! change it to `background`.

```
List(viewModel.exerciseSelection, id: \.id) { exercise in
   ,,,
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(Color.backgroundColor) //  1 absolute issue was here
```

and then You can either fallback to the `UIScrollView`:

```
init() {
    UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

---

##### 2.

Or hide the entire `List` by the `opacity` modifier to prevent branching and layout issues and unnecessary re-rendering like this:

```
List(...) { ... }
.opacity(viewModel.exerciseSelection.isEmpty ? 0 : 1)
```

---

##### 3.

Or you can use `LazyVStack` instead:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.exerciseSelection, id: \.self) { exercise in ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so your second option is my prefered one then, because I need the List for swipeOptions. Just saw the link on your comment to one of your posts and will watch the WWDC video, thanks for the tip, didn't know this would make a difference. I guess I will mark this as the solution.

Comment: You are free to choose but **note that** `List`s has some extra features like `swipeActions` that stacks don't and may require you to rearrange your layout because of `listRowBackground` and default layouts.

Answer (score -1):

If this happens to you, I just found that using an `if-else` statement can help. like so:

```
if list.isEmpty {
    Spacer() // needed in my case, because the View is only a VStack and not a ScrollView
} else {
    List {
    // content
    }
}
```

but still, there should be somehow an option to have a background without the need to check if a `List` is empty. Does someone know how?

Comment: This is not a good practice to branch the code like this. [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420479/5623035)

Comment: but its the only thing that works for me..

Answer (score -1):

Don't ask why, but if you wrap all into a `NavigationView` it works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var workouts: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Add") {
                    workouts.append("exercise \(workouts.count)")
                }
                
                List(workouts, id: \.self) { exercise in
                    Text(exercise)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have it inside a NavigationStack and it does not work, as describe in another comment with a ZStack ..

Comment: I know, but in a `NavigationView` it works.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, really weird behaviour ..

Comment: Agree, and it most definitely is a bug.