# Does SwiftUI not render/build/update views when their opacity is 0?

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a ViewModifier that looks like iOS alerts, except it's able to not have any buttons/actions on the popup. My main concern is that I'm using `.overlay {}` to show this alert on my `content` with a `.opacity(isPresented ? 1 : 0)` modifier. This alert would have a `ProgressView()` on it and I don't want SwiftUI to always be animating that `ProgressView()` behind the scenes.

I tried putting `Color.black.opacity(isPresented ? 1 : 0).allowsHitTesting(false)` on top of my content with `.overlay` and when the opacity was 0 it allowed me to tap any of the content that the `Color.black` would've been on top of, but when `isPresented` was `true` it didn't allow me to tap any of it. This seems like good enough evidence to me that it doesn't compute views with 0 opacities, but I was curious if anyone had any other insight.

Comment: SwiftUI from my experience will build views when opacity is 0 in addition to when the hidden modifier is added. You can test this with a text view where the text is returned from a function and having a print inside the function. However, when opacity is 0 the view will still take up "space" on the parent view, whereas hidden will not. Just out of curiosity -- why do you not want SwiftUI always animating the ProgressView behind the scenes? Is it rarely shown?

Comment: @ZachtheBoB Yes it would be rarely shown. It's supposed to say "Loading `ProgressView()`". It ended up working with a conditional `content.overlay { if isPresented { Views(/*ProgressView() in here somewhere) } }`, instead of changing opacity. I had already tried this but it didn't work correctly with using Transitions (because I want to scale it too) so I tried to use ternary modifiers and then went back and it started working, not sure what I changed though.

Comment: Maybe this Stack Post and the WWDC video at the bottom of the answer, gives you a better understanding of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490250/dynamically-hiding-view-in-swiftui/57420479#57420479

Comment: This is one of those occasions when using an `if` conditional in the view makes the most sense.