# Inconsistent spacing between navigation bar toolbar items in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have 2 trailing navigation bar buttons called Draw and Save.

On tapping Draw, I want 2 additional toolbar buttons to be added to the navigation bar.

This is how I am adding my nav bar buttons:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        PDFRepresentedView(drawingMode: $pdfViewerViewModel.drawingMode,
                           viewState: $pdfViewerViewModel.pdfViewState,
                           url: pdfViewerViewModel.pdfFileURL)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                nextPageNavBarItem
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                previousPageNavBarItem
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                drawNavBarItem
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                saveNavBarItem
                    .bold()
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                cancelNavBarTitle
                    .alert(isPresented: $shouldShowCancelAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text(pdfViewerViewModel.localizedText(for: .warningAlertTitle)),
                              message: Text(pdfViewerViewModel.localizedText(for: .cancelWarningMessage)),
                              primaryButton: .cancel(Text(pdfViewerViewModel.localizedText(for: .stayButtonTitle))),
                              secondaryButton: .destructive(Text(pdfViewerViewModel.localizedText(for: .leaveButtonTitle))) {
                            pdfViewerViewModel.shouldSaveData = false
                            dismiss()
                        })
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the buttons:

```
private var saveNavBarItem: some View {
    return AnyView(Button(action: {
        pdfViewerViewModel.shouldSaveData = false
        dismiss()
    }, label: {
        Text(pdfViewerViewModel.localizedText(for: .saveButtonTitle))
    }))
}

@ViewBuilder
private var drawNavBarItem: some View {
    Button(action: {
        pdfViewerViewModel.drawingMode.toggle()
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: pdfViewerViewModel.drawingIconName())
    })
}

@ViewBuilder
private var nextPageNavBarItem: some View {
    if pdfViewerViewModel.drawingMode {
        Button(action: {
            pdfViewerViewModel.pdfViewState = .nextPage
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: pdfViewerViewModel.nextPageIconName())
        })
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
private var previousPageNavBarItem: some View {
    if pdfViewerViewModel.drawingMode {
        Button(action: {
            pdfViewerViewModel.pdfViewState = .previousPage
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: pdfViewerViewModel.previousPageIconName())
        })
    }
}
```

So it starts out like this:

[image: Navigation view, Navigation stack bar button items swiftUI]

Then when I tap draw, the 2 other buttons get added, however, the spacing as you see is off between the draw and the previous (up arrow) button:

[image: SwiftUI Navigation Toolbar buttons]

If those 2 buttons are there from the beginning without any show / hide logic / binding, the spacing seems to be consistent:

[image: Toolbar Navigation bar buttons SwiftUI]

How can I achieve standard spacing when adding buttons to the bar button item at run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this problem, the gaps are consistent when I toggle the flag that controls their visibility. But a workaround might be to  show a hidden placeholder in the position where a button will be shown. Something like:

```swift
private func buttonPlaceholder(systemName: String) -> some View {
    Button {} label: {
        Image(systemName: systemName)
    }
    .hidden()
    .accessibilityHidden(true)
}
```

```swift
@ViewBuilder
private var nextPageNavBarItem: some View {
    if pdfViewerViewModel.drawingMode {
        Button(action: {
            pdfViewerViewModel.pdfViewState = .nextPage
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: pdfViewerViewModel.nextPageIconName())
        })
    } else {
        buttonPlaceholder(systemName: pdfViewerViewModel.nextPageIconName())
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did work, thanks. I ended up going with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228385/1619193

Comment: @ShawnFrank Pleased to hear it helped, thanks for accepting the answer. The other post has various answers, some just remove the label but leave the button active. I would suggest, it's not good for accessibility to have a button present that has no label. Also, if *button shapes* are enabled in the settings then a button with no label might suddenly becomes visible. Setting the button to `.hidden` is perhaps safer - it can either be the original button, or a placeholder that occupies the same space.

Comment: Yea I went with the hidden solution based on your answer here. The answer is similar to concept like yours, just had a modifier version. But yea, your answer pointed me in the right direction - Cheers.